# Cannot connect to a port on Ubuntu 22.04 x64

Tags: linux, socket

I have MySQL running on port 1835, as proven by running the command:

```
lsof -i:1835
```

The following was run to open the port on the firewall:

```
ufw allow 1835/tcp
ufw enable
ufw reload
```

But the port cannot be accessed from outside:

> C:\Users\Andrew>telnet 1.2.3.4 1835
> Connecting To 1.2.3.4...Could not open connection to the host, on port 1835: Connect failed

So for good measure I tried this (it didn't work either):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1835 -j ACCEPT
```

My knowledge of Linux is very limited, but I thought that this was sufficient. Please let me know if anything is missing..

In case it's relevant, this is being run on Vultr.. but I'm not using their firewall package, only the one on the box.

**Update:**
I ran netstat and got the following:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address         Foreign Address        State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1835        0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN
```

Here is the /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysql.cnf file:

```
[mysqld]
port=1835
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

Comment: *" MySQL running on port 1835"* - Mysql not only needs to run on port 1835 but also listen on the LAN IP address and not just localhost (127.0.0.1), in order to be accessible from the LAN.

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich :) I added a binding in mysql.cnf and restarted MySQL but it's still not working, unfortunately..

Comment: Your suggestion worked perfectly, thank you. It turns out I was editing the wrong file and needed to edit /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf, since the defaults were overriding the binding I had..

Comment: Please add thisd as an answer @SteffenUllrich. ;)